# R: easier method than data wrangling 2 dataframes

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to create 2 columns in my main data frame based on dates and logic from my tasks data frame (where order # matches). The below 2 solutions works where I `spread` the task dataframe into my main one and although the below examples run fairly fast, in my normal code, it is very memory intensive and takes a long time to compute (main dataframe has 800,000 rows and task dataframe as 20 or so tasks and probably 1.5M rows).

Is there a better solution to get columns G1 & G2 (example 1) and Gate1_end & Gate 2_end (eample 2)  without having to join my task dataframe to my main dataframe?

**Example 1**

```
maindf <- data.frame(
  Order = c(145,158,165,148,568,465,248,693,357,482),
  Location = c("US","US","Canada","US","France","US","Mexico","Mexico","UK","UK"),
  Animal = c("Cow","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat","Cow","Horse","Dog","Dog","Cat"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

Tasksdf_Start <- data.frame(
  Tasks_Start = c("RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start","QUOT_Start","QUOG_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start",
            "QUOT_Start", 
            "QUOG_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","QUOT_Start", 
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start","QUOT_Start","QUOG_Start", 
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start", 
            "QUOT_Start", 
            "QUOG_Start", 
            "RTQT_Start","QUOT_Start" 
            ),
  Dates = c("1/1/2020","1/2/2020","1/6/2020","1/20/2020", 
            "1/6/2020","1/9/2020", 
            "1/14/2020", 
            "1/17/2020", 
            "1/19/2020","1/8/2020", 
            "1/15/2020","1/3/2020", "1/6/2020","1/19/2020", 
            "1/22/2020","1/25/2020", 
            "1/1/2020", 
            "1/6/2020", 
            "1/24/2020","1/14/2020"
            ),
  Order = c(145, 145, 145, 145, 
            158, 158,
            165, 
            148, 
            568, 568, 
            465, 465, 465, 465, 
            248, 248,
            693, 
            357, 
            482, 482
            ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

Tasksdf_End <- data.frame(
  Tasks_End = c("CRDT_End", "CUST_End", "VEND_End",
            "CUST_End",
            "CRDT_End",
            "CUST_End",
            "CRDT_End", "CUST_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "CRDT_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "CRDT_End"
            ),
  Dates = c("1/22/2020", "1/18/2020", "1/5/2020",
            "1/15/2020",
            "1/16/2020",
            "1/18/2020",
            "1/7/2020", "1/24/2020",
            "1/1/2020",
            "1/18/2020",
            "1/8/2020",
            "1/4/2020",
            "1/6/2020"
            ),
  Order = c(145, 145, 145,
            158,
            165,
            148,
            568, 568,
            465,
            248,
            693,
            357,
            482
            ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


dfS <- left_join(maindf, Tasksdf_Start, by = c("Order" = "Order")) %>%
  spread(Tasks_Start, Dates)

dfE <- left_join(maindf, Tasksdf_End, by = c("Order" = "Order")) %>%
  spread(Tasks_End, Dates) 
dfE <- dfE %>%
  select(1,4:ncol(dfE))

df <- left_join(dfS, dfE, by = c("Order" = "Order"))

df$G1 <- pmin(df$QUOG_Start, df$QUOT_Start, df$RTQR_Start, df$RTQT_Start, na.rm = TRUE)

df$G2 <- pmax(df$CRDT_End, df$CUST_End, df$VEND_End, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Example 2** *(Very similar to example 1 but more complicated logic)*

```
maindf <- data.frame(
  Order = c(145,158,165,148,568,465,248,693,357,482),
  Gates = c("Gate1","Gate2","Gate2","Gate3","Gate2","Gate4","Gate1","Gate1","Gate2","Gate3"),
  Animal = c("Cow","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat","Cow","Horse","Dog","Dog","Cat"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

Tasksdf_Start <- data.frame(
  Tasks_Start = c("RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start","QUOT_Start","QUOG_Start", "CRDT_Start", "CUST_Start", "VEND_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start", "CUST_Start", "CRDT_Start",
            "QUOT_Start", "CRDT_Start",
            "QUOG_Start", "CUST_Start", "CRDT_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","QUOT_Start","CRDT_Start", "CUST_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start","QUOT_Start","QUOG_Start", "VEND_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","RTQR_Start", "CRDT_Start",
            "QUOT_Start", "VEND_Start", "CRDT_Start",
            "QUOG_Start", "VEND_Start",
            "RTQT_Start","QUOT_Start", "CRDT_Start"
            ),
  Dates = c("1/1/2020","1/2/2020","1/6/2020","1/20/2020", "1/8/2020","1/19/2020","1/8/2020",
            "1/6/2020","1/9/2020", "1/1/2020","1/9/2020",
            "1/14/2020",  "1/1/2020",
            "1/17/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020",
            "1/19/2020","1/8/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020",
            "1/15/2020","1/3/2020", "1/6/2020","1/19/2020", "1/1/2020", 
            "1/22/2020","1/25/2020",  "1/1/2020",
            "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020",
            "1/6/2020",  "1/1/2020",
            "1/24/2020","1/14/2020", "1/1/2020"
            ),
  Order = c(145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145,
            158, 158, 158, 158,
            165, 165,
            148, 148, 148, 
            568, 568, 568, 568,
            465, 465, 465, 465, 465,
            248, 248, 248,
            693, 693, 693, 
            357, 357, 
            482, 482,  482
            ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

Tasksdf_End <- data.frame(
  Tasks_End = c("CRDT_End", "CUST_End", "VEND_End",
            "CUST_End",
            "CRDT_End",
            "CUST_End",
            "CRDT_End", "CUST_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "CRDT_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "VEND_End",
            "CRDT_End"
            ),
  Dates = c("1/22/2020", "1/18/2020", "1/5/2020",
            "1/15/2020",
            "1/16/2020",
            "1/18/2020",
            "1/7/2020", "1/24/2020",
            "1/1/2020",
            "1/18/2020",
            "1/8/2020",
            "1/4/2020",
            "1/6/2020"
            ),
  Order = c(145, 145, 145,
            158,
            165,
            148,
            568, 568,
            465,
            248,
            693,
            357,
            482
            ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


dfS <- left_join(maindf, Tasksdf_Start, by = c("Order" = "Order")) %>%
  spread(Tasks_Start, Dates)

dfE <- left_join(maindf, Tasksdf_End, by = c("Order" = "Order")) %>%
  spread(Tasks_End, Dates) 
dfE <- dfE %>%
  select(1,4:ncol(dfE))

df <- left_join(dfS, dfE, by = c("Order" = "Order"))


df$Gate1_End <- if_else(df$Gates == "Gate1" | df$Gates == "Gate0", as.character(NA), pmin(df$QUOG_Start, df$QUOT_Start, df$RTQR_Start, df$RTQT_Start, na.rm = TRUE))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Gate2Open = rowSums(!is.na(select(.,one_of(c('CRDT_Start', 'CUST_Start', 'VEND_Start'))))),
         Gate2Close = rowSums(!is.na(select(.,one_of(c('CRDT_End', 'CUST_End', 'VEND_End')))))
  )

df$Gate2_End <- if_else(df$Gates == "Gate2" | df$Gates == "Gate1" | df$Gates == "Gate0", as.character(NA), 
                         if_else((df$Gate2Close - df$Gate2Open) == 0, 
                                 pmax(df$CRDT_End, df$CUST_End, df$VEND_End, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                 as.character(NA))
)
```

Comment: Why don't you consider using `data.table` ? 
I had once to merge two ~6M rows dataframes. Using dplyr::join() failed (lack of memory on my laptop), using `merge.data.table` took ... 21 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, in my actual code I am using `data.table` and it's not `merge` that is taking a long time, it's the `spread` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mutate`you don't have to create wide data frames to add the summary column:

EXAMPLE 1:

```
# calculate min for the START values
start <- Tasksdf_Start %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(G1=min(Dates, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Order, G1) %>% 
  summarise_each(lst(max)) %>% # merge identical rows
  rename(G1=max)

# calculate max for the END vales
end <- Tasksdf_End %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(G2=max(Dates, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Order, G2) %>%
  summarise_each(lst(max)) %>% # merge identical rows
  rename(G2=max)

# join everything
maindf <- maindf %>%
  full_join(start, end, by ="Order")
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
# calculate min for START values
start <- Tasksdf_Start %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(Gate1_End=min(Dates, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Order, Gate1_End) %>% 
  summarise_each(lst(max)) %>% # merge identical rows
  rename(Gate1_End=max)

# sum up cases defined in c('CRDT_Start', 'CUST_Start', 'VEND_Start')
Gate2Open <- Tasksdf_Start %>%
  filter(Tasks_Start %in% c('CRDT_Start', 'CUST_Start', 'VEND_Start')) %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(Gate2Open = n()) %>%
  dplyr::select(Order, Gate2Open) %>% 
  summarise_each(lst(max)) %>% # merge identical rows
  rename(Gate2Open = max)

# calculate max for END values & sum up cases for "_End" columns
end <- Tasksdf_End %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(Gate2Close = n())%>%
  mutate(Gate2_End=max(Dates, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Order, Gate2_End, Gate2Close) %>%
  summarise_each(lst(max)) %>% # merge identical rows
  rename(Gate2_End=Gate2_End_max, Gate2Close = Gate2Close_max) 

# join & apply conditions
maindf <- maindf %>%
  full_join(end, by ="Order") %>%
  full_join(start, by = "Order") %>%
  full_join(Gate2Open, by = "Order") %>%
  group_by(Order) %>%
  mutate(Gate1_End = case_when(Gates == "Gate1" | Gates == "Gate2" ~ as.character(NA),
                               Gates != "Gate1" & Gates != "Gate2" ~ Gate1_End), 
         Gate2_End = case_when(Gates == "Gate2" | Gates == "Gate1" | Gates == "Gate0" ~ as.character(NA), 
                               Gate2Close - Gate2Open == 0 ~ Gate2_End))
```

Maybe there would be a more elegant way, but like this you avoid `spread()`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work (for example 1)! Any thoughts on example 2?

Comment: Did you mean the column names ending with "_start" in ````Gate2Open = rowSums(!is.na(select(.,one_of(c('CRDT_Start', 'CUST_Start', 'VEND_Start')))))````? Because these columns don't exist in your data frame... Or would it just be 0?

Comment: I added a solution for example 2 to my answer!

Comment: Hi @Em, the columns `CRDT_Start`, `CUST_Start`, `VEND_Start` exist in the 2nd example dataframe `Taskdf_Start` (become columns after `spread`). Your solution doesn't produce the right answer... but it's a good start! I'll be trying to make it work on my end and see if I can get it.

Comment: Great, I came to the almost same code too! Thank you so much, never would have figured it out without your help!